# Random 554 synchronization error on server

Tags: email, networking, smtp

We can send mails across the network from 1 server to another via a centralized smtp server.
However, the we get a synchronization error on the server randomly.

So for example if we send a simple mail 6 times  the 3rd one fails with a synchronization error.
When we look at the network packet we have

RCPT TO: abc@company.com

C:QUIT  -- This for some reason is called before the smtp server processes the request.

Any clues why this with happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This questions looks identical to this one? Try its answer below:
https://serverfault.com/a/583953

Try increasing the timeout on the client side?